# How to mount network share (SAMBA windows share) with running container in openshift

Tags: openshift, mount

I have tried cifs for mounting network share with host then host to docker container. That is working. But I want to mount direct with container.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount cifs through flexVolume driver as follows.

- [Mounting CIFS Shares in OpenShift](https://blog.openshift.com/mounting-cifs-shares-in-openshift/)
- [CIFS Flexvolume Plugin for Kubernetes](https://github.com/fstab/cifs#cifs-flexvolume-plugin-for-kubernetes)

The cifs can use like this, refer above links for cifs testing.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: busybox
  namespace: default
spec:
  containers:
  - name: busybox
    image: busybox
    command:
      - sleep
      - "3600"
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    volumeMounts:
    - name: test
      mountPath: /data
  volumes:
  - name: test
    flexVolume:
      driver: "fstab/cifs"
      fsType: "cifs"
      secretRef:
        name: "cifs-secret"
      options:
        networkPath: "//server/share"
        mountOptions: "dir_mode=0755,file_mode=0644,noperm"
```

Comment: Does the solution support Active Directory Authentication for authorising access to smb share?

Comment: @SerG Did you find out if this was possible? I am trying to achieve the same

Comment: @Sahil No, I've just chosen another architecture.

Comment: @SerG Thanks, for Someone coming here in future - looks like CIFS Flexvolume Plugin for Kubernetes can achieve this